# COB lights using 4 aaa batteries

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I bought a few COB lights from Harbor Freight, they look like light switches. I would like to hook them up to a wall mount power supply, I think they are wired in series. Also, I would like any information on COB lights and how to tell what voltage, watts  and amps COB lights are and how to tell? Is there a website that shows this? I bought on COB light strip but don't know volts, watts nor amps, how can I tell?

Comment: COB means "chip on board" and not something terribly special about the LED, itself. It's just a way of avoiding some of the per-LED packaging costs.

Comment: No datasheet or specs?

Comment: Also be aware that many companies are using "COB" as a promotional word to sell relatively inferior LEDs in a way that makes them appear to be more powerful than they are.  With most of these you can see that there are a smaller number of smaller LED dies spread over a large area of phosphorus.  Better cobs will use larger individual dies at a higher density, The ones you have have a built in driver/resistor, so you may want to just turn them on and measure voltage and current to get the rating if you have undocumented chips.

Comment: Also bear in mind some battery operated LED products are designed with the assumption that input voltage will drop as the batteries are depleted and will overheat if continuously exposed to full fresh battery voltage.  If your LEDs use resistance to regulate rather than a switcher or constant current driver, you should take this into account.

Answer (score 0):

```
Name    200 Lumen LED Super Bright Flip Light
SKU     63922
Battery(s) Included (y/n)   Yes
Battery(s) required     4 AAA
Run time on full charge (hours)     3 hours
```

[*ref*](https://www.harborfreight.com/200-lumen-led-super-bright-flip-light-63922.html)

Rechargeable AAA cells ...hmm If *[Energizers](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/nh12-700.pdf)*
then

```
Nominal Voltage: 1.2 Volts
Rated Capacity: 700 mAh at 21°C (70°F)

thus 4.8V  for 4 x NiMH
assuming 700mAh/3h = 233 mA max
some white LEDs can use 2.9 to 3.1V or 3V avg *233mA = 700mW
but 200 lumen / 700mW is very expensive  and not correct
I suspect it only starts at 200 lumens then goes dimmer and fades for the last hour.
```

> These are only $1.99 (cheap)

```
So using more typical specs of decent COB LEDs of 140 Lumens / W     
200 lumens = 1.4W or 466 mA and only lasts 1.5 hr in theory then goes dim 
then it will draw less current for the last part of 3h or my guess the last 1.5h
```

**So I expect 4.8V ~ at < = 330 mA is what I compute or 1.5W @ 133 lumens per watt.**

What do you want for 2 bucks?